# Extremely slow Wordpress performance on parallels plesk

Tags: wordpress, performance, server, plesk

After completing local development of a wordpress website I tested it on my own sever (Dreamhost, cpanel) and everything seemed fine. However, before taking the site live on the client server's main domain (Parallels Plesk ) I decided to install it on a folder as a test

After uploading the files and connecting the database, I saw that the site loads extremely slowly. Here is what I have tried to remedy the situation:

1. I have tried using an external database (on my own Dreamhost server) This is equally slow.
2. I have tried loading a plain HTML file - this seems to work just fine.

Here are the results of a pingdom test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMBHA.jpg
Here is a screenshot of Chrome Developer tools:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYFCJ.png (again the issue seems to be with the initial request?)
The url with the issue is: www.qeprize.org/new/

In this case the main domain also has a Wordpress install which seems to run just fine.

Unfortunately I am a front-end developer and thus lack experience in the area, contacting webhost support is not an option. I am guessing this a Paralles/Plex configuration issue and has something to do with PHP, could anyone please advise on how can I configure the server?

Update:
Seem to have identified the issue. It was being caused by a plugin called layer slider which was trying to load the wrong urls; still trying to track the details down. But all i did was go through the error log and disbale anything that showed an error.

Comment: I'm having several WordPress sites running, using it as an CMS on Ubuntu and Plesk. And they have no such performance issues. I can confirm it is the initial request which takes longest. But I doubt it is related to Plesk / PHP. It is difficult to say whats the cause without having Backend Access. Does the backend load that slow aswell? Or is it only Front End related? It might be Plugins or Cache. Or even some redundancy in loading. It takes more than 40s to load. Maybe a faulty PHP script is executed and is cancelled by the 30s PHP execution time.

Comment: Hay Mario, no the back end is loading very quickly and there is another wordpress installation on the server that runs very smoothly. Could you please advise on how i can identify any PHP issues? Where would the error log be stored in this case? ( ... Apologies that I am asking such basic questions) Also why would the same wordpress set up (copied using duplicator) perform smoothly on dreamhost and locally? if there is a php error?

Comment: Can you Benchmark your Script to see which part is the slowest? Is it the initial connection to the Database? Is it some Query? If we not know the part of your Application which has the problem, there are to much possibilitys it can be.

Comment: And what is your MySQL configuration? Communication via IP or DNS? How much Ram?

Comment: @LukaDadiani Assuming your server system is a Linux, have a look in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, which is default. Or try `tail /var/log/php_errors.log` in a SSH console. The PHP error log can be set in `php.ini`

Comment: @LukaDadiani When the backend loads fast, it is probably some frontend script / plugin which causes the problem. For me it sounds like some (external?) PHP script is executed and then cancelled by the 30s execution limit of PHP.

Comment: @marioWerner Sorry I thought you meant the plex panel back-end; the wordpress back-end itself is equally slow

Comment: Plex != Plesk. You should update that tag. ;)

Answer (score 1):

your questions is not clear enough. to make it clear you need to know the cause. 
perhaps it is because **Plesk** , **PHP** or **Database**.

install a clean version if it`s ok therefore the problem is about your wordpress.

wordpress if two part PHP and DATABASE. check statistics on your hosting panel if your cpu usage is not that much high it`s because of your data base for this problem check this way. run your wordpress on chrome press F12 and check network tab if all front and admin pages load slow? like this picture?

[image]